# How to boost requestAnimationFrame performance?

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

It is my first time trying to create smooth animations using rAF and I would like some insight from more experinced developers. Basicaly I have 16 elements with x,y coordinates and on mousemove over their parent container, all elements move a set amount in the opposite direction. When I do tests on lower-end machines there is some stutter. Is there any technique I am not aware of that can boost my animation performance?

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(() => {
const animCont = document.querySelector('.shop-header-container');
const animContWidth = animCont.offsetWidth;
const animContHeight = animCont.offsetHeight;
const leftOffset = animCont.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const topOffset = document.querySelector('#primary').offsetTop;
const animImgs = animCont.querySelectorAll('.elem');
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
let mouseOver = false;
let positions = [
  {
    id: 82,
    start: {
      x: 0.596,
      y: 0.654,
    },
    range: 0.4,
  }
...
]
positions.forEach(el => {
  el.target = {};
  el.current = {};
})
function updateElements(){
  mouseTargetX = (mouseX - leftOffset) / animContWidth;
  mouseTargetY = (mouseY + topOffset) / animContHeight;
  positions.forEach((el,i) => {
    if (mouseOver) {
      el.target.x = ((mouseTargetX - el.start.x) * -el.range + el.start.x ) * animContWidth;
      el.target.y = ((mouseTargetY - el.start.y) * -el.range + el.start.y ) * animContHeight;
    } else {
      el.target.x = el.start.x * animContWidth;
      el.target.y = el.start.y * animContHeight;
    }

    if(!el.current.x) {
      el.current.x = el.target.x;
      el.current.y = el.target.y;
    } else {
      el.current.x = el.current.x + (el.target.x - el.current.x)*0.1;
      el.current.y = el.current.y + (el.target.y - el.current.y)*0.1;
    }

    animImgs[i].style.transform = 'translate3d('+el.current.x+'px,'+el.current.y+'px,0)';
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(updateElements);
}
updateElements();
function animContMouseEnter(e){
  mouseOver = true;
}
function animContMouseLeave(){
  mouseOver = false;
}
function animContMouseOver(e){
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}
animCont.addEventListener("mousemove",animContMouseOver,false);
animCont.addEventListener("mouseenter",animContMouseEnter,false);
animCont.addEventListener("mouseleave",animContMouseLeave,false);
});
}(jQuery));
```

Here is the js code.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame can only do so much. You need to think about what processes you are triggering when it comes to browser performance.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/unnecessary-paints/        
https://css-tricks.com/browser-painting-and-considerations-for-web-performance/

One way to optimize what you're doing may be to utilize transforms instead of manipulating x, y coordinates for every mousemove triggered. Then, once the mouse leaves the area, use the transforms to recalculate the x, y's.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You seem not to take into account the current time (as provided to you by requestAnimationFrame), which is integral for an animation

Comment: @DevinFields thank you, that is an interesting read. What exactly do you mean by 'utilizing transforms', am I not using the css transform function?

Comment: @Bergi hi, can you be a bit more specific about 'taking into account the current time' when animating? I would like to learn more about this and every method there is that boosts performance, but how exactly do I search information for it?

Comment: @HristoHristov [This page](https://www.viget.com/articles/time-based-animation/) explains the concept well, not sure whether the terminology is correct or a good search term though (and no, it does not necessarily "boost performance", as it's more computationally intensive, but it should help removing the stutter)

Comment: @HristoHristov Sorry, i missed the transform line. I do wonder if you need to use translate3d, though. Regular translate may be more than enough to move them around.